# Infrastructure-oriented testing Methodology

Tags: deployment, testing, infrastructure

In software development, there are plenty of testing methodology that one can adopt during the software lifecycle.
Is there anyone aware of a testing methodology that is infrastructure oriented or that can simply be applied to implement tests for an infrastructure instead of a software ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a developing field, but have a look at a question that covers some of your questions: [Best practice for testing chef recipes?](https://serverfault.com/questions/299895/best-practice-for-testing-chef-recipes)